# pass a ToolPart value to a user control of a custom WebPart in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

I have created a Custom WebPart that has a UserControl. I have added a Custom ToolPart(dropdown) to it as well.
What i want to achieve is that as a selection is made in the Custom ToolPart Dropdown;the value is to be passed into the code behind of the UserControl. I tried to use the Custom properties of the ToolPart to pass the dropdown Value but couldnt do so. Then,i declared a public property in the UserControl Class but that worked onl

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Synchanges()` and `ApplyChanges()` to pass values between ToolPart and WebPart. Once the value is passed from ToolPart to WebPart you can access the web part property from within the UserControl by using a hidden field and assigning the value to the hidden field and retrieving it from the user control.

Comment: Thanks for responding to the above query. But how can i assign value to the hidden field of the user control in the ApplyChanges() method as the scope of the hidden field is within the user control itself and ApplyChanges() method is in toolpart class??

Comment: You got me wrong. ApplyChanges() -> Web Part Property -> Web Part Hidden Field -> Read from User Control.

Comment: apply changes function is in the custom toolpart class. and how to access a hidden field from a custom toolpart class into web usercontrol code behind class??

Comment: I've put the web part property in between ApplyChanges() and the web part hidden field in the data flow. First you need to assign it to the public property of the web part class. From there you need set it to the hidden field of the web part. Then from the user control you can read the parent container (which is the webpart) hidden field.

Comment: okay.. just to bring to your knowledge;in my case usercontrol is .ascx file seperate and i want to take the value in it. this usercontrol is not in the WebPart class